# Having some issue with a for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

i have this loop which calculate the increase temp by 10 deg every 2 min.
i need to fix the temp at 120 deg when reach 16 min and above
I've tried many solution but none of them work??
any suggestion???

```
var temp = 30,
    min = 0;
    console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 25; min++) {

   if (min % 2 === 0) {
       temp += 10;
       console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + 
                    ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
   }

   if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 25) {
       console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
   }
}
```

the output should be something like that :

```
Cooking started at 30 deg
Minutes passed: 0, we are cooking at 40 deg
Minutes passed: 2, we are cooking at 50 deg
Minutes passed: 4, we are cooking at 60 deg
Minutes passed: 6, we are cooking at 70 deg
Minutes passed: 8, we are cooking at 80 deg
Minutes passed: 10, we are cooking at 90 deg
Minutes passed: 12, we are cooking at 100 deg
Minutes passed: 14, we are cooking at 110 deg
Minutes passed: 16, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 18, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 20, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 22, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 24, we are cooking at 120 deg
Total minutes of cooking is 25 min
```

Comment: If you know that you need to fix the temp to 120 degrees (after 16 minutes), then why have the loop go more than 16 minutes?

Answer (score 3):

It seems strange that you'd want to keep looping after hitting your known max value. The simplest thing to do is to just set the maximum loop count to `<=16` since you know that you need to end there.

```js
var temp = 30,
    min = 0;
    console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 16; min++) {

   if (min % 2 === 0) {
       temp += 10;
       console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + 
                    ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
   }

   if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 16) {
       console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
   }
}
```

Or, if you must go to 25 minutes, you just need to include a test for 16 minutes and set the `temp` accordingly:

```js
var temp = 30,
    min = 0;
    console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 25; min++) {

   if(min >= 16) {
      // If we've arrived in this branch, at least 16 minutes of cooking has already happened
      temp = 120;  // Set temp to max
      console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
   } else if (min % 2 === 0) {
       // If we've arrived in this branch, we must be less than 16 minutes in and 
       // we are on an even minute, so proceed as normal
       temp += 10;
       console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
   }

   if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 25) {
       console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
   }
}
```

Comment: This code now has a condition that cannot be met (min === 25).

Comment: i need the min to continue by 2 while the temp stays at 120
Minutes passed: 16, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 18, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 20, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 22, we are cooking at 120 deg
Minutes passed: 24, we are cooking at 120 deg

Comment: @MohamedAttia I understand what you want (and my updated answer does this). I just don't understand why you want it.

Comment: @Trioj That was the entire point of the first code snippet. If you know you need to stop increasing the temperature after 16 minutes, then why count to 25?

Comment: @ScottMarcus then why did you leave an if block in that checks min === 25 in your code that can't count to 25? That's *my* point. Look at your first code snippet. You cannot reach the final if block because min can never be equal to 25 anymore. Your suggested code has a bug in it. That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @Trioj That's not my code. It was just copied from the original. It's irrelevant to the answer, but I've updated it nonetheless.

Comment: It became your code when you altered it and suggested it as an answer. I feel like you should clean up the bug left in it by your alteration. I see that you did. I no longer have an issue.

Comment: @Trioj No, that was not "my" code. Look at the OP, it's the OP's code that was inadvertently left in, but isn't relevant to the point my first code snippet is trying to make.

Comment: You changed the 25 to a 16, correct? You made that edit. Then you left unreachable code behind.

Comment: @Trioj You are splitting hairs. What you are not processing is that the code you are talking about is not relevant to the posted answer. At SO, we don't always fix every aspect of someone's code when that fix doesn't really relate to the problem or the solution.

Comment: Look, I'm just explaining my comment. You seemed to think my problem was the count. It wasn't. I understand that the thing I'm objecting to is unnecessary to solve the problem. But why do you think you shouldn't clean that up or remove it? Or that it might seem odd or confusing to a reader?

Comment: @Trioj Explained thoroughly in my previous comments.

Comment: And I simply believe that omitting it is less ridiculous (and lazy) than including it when it doesn't work. I understand that you disagree. I don't think we're confused about what the other is saying anymore, we just disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Code can be much reduced if you just apply a formula for `temp` in terms of `min`. Using `Math.min` you can make sure the temperature never exceeds a certain value. And as you only print something every two minutes, you could make your loop take steps of that many minutes. Finally, as the 25-minute message only occurs once and at the end, it is better placed outside of the loop:

```js
console.log("Cooking started at 30 deg");
for (var min = 0; min <= 25; min+=2) {
   var temp = Math.min(120, 40 + min*5);
   console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
}
console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
```

Comment: @McHat, really? I think all the `%` and `if` and `!==` and `===`, require a lot of reading before one gets what is happening. All that is not necessary. Here one can concentrate really on `Math.min(120, 40 + min*5)` which has about all the info that is needed to understand the algorithm.

Comment: @McHat Reduced code that leverages perfectly legitimate aspects of the language is perfectly fine. This is not "much harder" to read or follow as long as you understand `Math.min`. Don't be afraid of refactoring.

Comment: It's really just about ease of reading for me.  I dislike this solution because I prefer to read code that is verbose and explicit rather than terse and arcane.

Comment: @McHat, what exactly do you find *arcane* with this simple code?

Comment: @McHat You are certainly entitled to you opinion, but realize that it is just that when you place a label on someone else's code. "terse and arcane" are hardly appropriate terms for this code. `Math.min` is not arcane. `Math` is a native JS object. It is an integral part of the language. That is not an opinion. And "terse"? Don't hate a simple statement for its brevity, when a more lengthy way to use that statement doesn't exist.

Comment: it is 100% my opinion, like you said. it would take me longer to understand what you wrote there than what OP wrote above because I would have to stop and do algebra to figure out how the temperature would change. yes it is a simple problem but my aging mind doesn't have time for that kind of BS. IMO, if you can make it explicit and simple to understand how temp is changing over time, you should do it.  that is all

Comment: @McHat Actually, it's trincot's code, not mine, but again if it's *your aging mind* that doesn't want to do the math, fine. But, again, be careful labeling someone's very good code as "terse" and "arcane" when that is completely untrue. It's important to remember that Stack Overflow is a knowledge base and a learning tool for others. A newbie could read your comment and think that this was not a good solution, when, in fact, it is really a very good solution. It's just one that you, personally, don't care for.

Comment: and thanks to folks like you (and me) this won't be possible because we are all too opinionated and pedantic to let things like this slide, and this is why SO has been such a great place for so long...  also remember that *your nimble mind* has its own opinions about how things should be done--and that doesn't necessarily invalidate *my aging mind's* point of view

Answer (score 2):

Just put a condition that checks if time is greater than 16 minutes and then sets the temp to 120.  Otherwise, increment it by 5:

```
var temp = 30,
min = 0;
console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 25; min++) {

   if (min >= 16) {
       temp = 120;
   } else {
       temp += 5;
   }

   if (min % 2 === 0) {
       console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + 
                    ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
   }

   if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 25) {
       console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
   }
}
```

Also, it is good to keep things like logging and temperature setting in separate codeblocks so that things don't get too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to stop modifying `temp` once it reaches a value of 120. You have two options: `break;` or `continue;`.

`break;` will stop the `for` loop altogether, and it will stop looping through after you call it.

`continue;` will just skip the rest of that loop for that iteration. If you want to preserve the rest of the loop once you hit 120, this is the one you want. Example:

```
var temp = 30,
min = 0;
console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 25; min++) {

  if(temp >= 120) {
    continue;
    // or 'break;' if you're done with the entire loop.
  }

  if (min % 2 === 0) {
      temp += 10;
      console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + 
                ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
  }

  if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 25) {
      console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
  }
}
```

Haven't thoroughly tested that, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use break after you have check your incremented variable `temp`.

```js
console.clear();
var temp = 30,
  min = 0;
console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 25; min++) {
  if (temp >= 120) {
    break;
  }

  if (min % 2 === 0) {
    temp += 10;
    console.log("Minutes passed: " + min +
      ", we are cooking at " + temp + " deg");
  }

  if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 25) {
    console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a ternary operator condition inside the `console.log()` to minimize the code:

```js
var temp = 30,
    min = 0;
    console.log("Cooking started at " + temp + " deg");

for (min = 0; min <= 25; min++) {
   if (min % 2 === 0) {
       temp += 10;
       console.log("Minutes passed: " + min + 
                    ", we are cooking at " + (temp>120?120:temp) + " deg");
   }

   if (min % 2 !== 0 && min === 25) {
       console.log("Total minutes of cooking is 25 min");
   }
}
```

Explanation :

```
(temp>120?120:temp)
// shorthand to
if (temp>120) { 120 } else { temp }
```

Comment: ...or you could do something that is easy for the next developer to read and understand.  Nesting ternary expressions inline with your printed output is not a good habit to develop.  I might even call that an antipattern.

Comment: About not being easy, I might agree, but about being a bad habit, I don't, since it's just outputting a value whose existence and type are known and guaranteed.